# How to increase the counter value after every select operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a login table with a username and password. I want to set a counter there with initial value = 0 and increase the counter to 1 the first time anyone runs "select * from login table."

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this *type* of thing in the database is with a trigger, but there is no `SELECT` trigger in SQL Server. Your better bet is to put this logging at your application level. But before doing that, you should seriously consider *why* you're doing this.